# I'm attempting to union 8 Data Extensions in Marketing Cloud but I'm getting errors on the syntax

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have 8 data extensions that I want to union all into one master data extension.  All the column headers are the same for each DE and the master DE.  The only differences in the 8 DEs are the records.  They are all unique.

My first attempt was to have 8 separate queries that push data into the master DE.  That was causing a longer processing time than I wanted.  Now I want to run one query that captures all the data in each of the 8 DEs and union all into the master DE.  I added part of the query below. The original is pretty long.

```
UNION ALL

SELECT
LINE_OF_BUSINESS
,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE
,CLIENT_ID
,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY
,CLIENT_NAME
,LSTNAM
,FSTNAM
,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER
,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO
,SSN
,RELCOD
,GENDER
,BTHDAT
,ADDRESS1
,ADDRESS2
,CITY
,STACOD
,POSTAL_CODE
,EFFDAT
,TERM_DATE
,AGE
,GROUP
,BENEPKG
,NETWORK
,MOBILE
,LOCALE
,Email_Address
,COMM_Preferences
,LANGUAGE
,Subscriber_Key
,DSS_Start
,DSS_End
,CONSULT_INCLUDED
,SMS
,CREATED_DATE
,INDUSTRY
,PRODUCT1
,PRODUCT2
,PRODUCT3
,PRODUCT4
,PRODUCT5
,PRODUCT6
,PRODUCT7
,PRODUCT8
,PRODUCT9
,PRODUCT10
FROM NGS_BOB

UNION ALL

SELECT
LINE_OF_BUSINESS
,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE
,CLIENT_ID
,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY
,CLIENT_NAME
,LSTNAM
,FSTNAM
,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER
,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO
,SSN
,RELCOD
,GENDER
,BTHDAT
,ADDRESS1
,ADDRESS2
,CITY
,STACOD
,POSTAL_CODE
,EFFDAT
,TERM_DATE
,AGE
,GROUP
,BENEPKG
,NETWORK
,MOBILE
,LOCALE
,Email_Address
,COMM_Preferences
,LANGUAGE
,Subscriber_Key
,DSS_Start
,DSS_End
,CONSULT_INCLUDED
,SMS
,CREATED_DATE
,INDUSTRY
,PRODUCT1
,PRODUCT2
,PRODUCT3
,PRODUCT4
,PRODUCT5
,PRODUCT6
,PRODUCT7
,PRODUCT8
,PRODUCT9
,PRODUCT10
FROM FMH_BOB

UNION ALL

SELECT
LINE_OF_BUSINESS
,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE
,CLIENT_ID
,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY
,CLIENT_NAME
,LSTNAM
,FSTNAM
,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER
,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO
,SSN
,RELCOD
,GENDER
,BTHDAT
,ADDRESS1
,ADDRESS2
,CITY
,STACOD
,POSTAL_CODE
,EFFDAT
,TERM_DATE
,AGE
,GROUP
,BENEPKG
,NETWORK
,MOBILE
,LOCALE
,Email_Address
,COMM_Preferences
,LANGUAGE
,Subscriber_Key
,DSS_Start
,DSS_End
,CONSULT_INCLUDED
,SMS
,CREATED_DATE
,INDUSTRY
,PRODUCT1
,PRODUCT2
,PRODUCT3
,PRODUCT4
,PRODUCT5
,PRODUCT6
,PRODUCT7
,PRODUCT8
,PRODUCT9
,PRODUCT10
FROM EHC_BOB

UNION ALL
```

Comment: Be careful, this may time out depending on how large your DEs are.

Comment: Just take out the union all on the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT LINE_OF_BUSINESS ,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE ,CLIENT_ID ,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY ,CLIENT_NAME ,LSTNAM ,FSTNAM ,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER ,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO ,SSN ,RELCOD ,GENDER ,BTHDAT ,ADDRESS1 ,ADDRESS2 ,CITY ,STACOD ,POSTAL_CODE ,EFFDAT ,TERM_DATE ,AGE ,GROUP ,BENEPKG ,NETWORK ,MOBILE ,LOCALE ,Email_Address ,COMM_Preferences ,LANGUAGE ,Subscriber_Key ,DSS_Start ,DSS_End ,CONSULT_INCLUDED ,SMS ,CREATED_DATE ,INDUSTRY ,PRODUCT1 ,PRODUCT2 ,PRODUCT3 ,PRODUCT4 ,PRODUCT5 ,PRODUCT6 ,PRODUCT7 ,PRODUCT8 ,PRODUCT9 ,PRODUCT10 FROM NGS_BOB

UNION

SELECT LINE_OF_BUSINESS ,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE ,CLIENT_ID ,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY ,CLIENT_NAME ,LSTNAM ,FSTNAM ,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER ,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO ,SSN ,RELCOD ,GENDER ,BTHDAT ,ADDRESS1 ,ADDRESS2 ,CITY ,STACOD ,POSTAL_CODE ,EFFDAT ,TERM_DATE ,AGE ,GROUP ,BENEPKG ,NETWORK ,MOBILE ,LOCALE ,Email_Address ,COMM_Preferences ,LANGUAGE ,Subscriber_Key ,DSS_Start ,DSS_End ,CONSULT_INCLUDED ,SMS ,CREATED_DATE ,INDUSTRY ,PRODUCT1 ,PRODUCT2 ,PRODUCT3 ,PRODUCT4 ,PRODUCT5 ,PRODUCT6 ,PRODUCT7 ,PRODUCT8 ,PRODUCT9 ,PRODUCT10 FROM FMH_BOB

UNION

SELECT LINE_OF_BUSINESS ,LOB_PRODUCT_CODE ,CLIENT_ID ,SOURCE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY ,CLIENT_NAME ,LSTNAM ,FSTNAM ,PS_MEMBER_NUMBER ,PUBLIC_MEMBER_NO ,SSN ,RELCOD ,GENDER ,BTHDAT ,ADDRESS1 ,ADDRESS2 ,CITY ,STACOD ,POSTAL_CODE ,EFFDAT ,TERM_DATE ,AGE ,GROUP ,BENEPKG ,NETWORK ,MOBILE ,LOCALE ,Email_Address ,COMM_Preferences ,LANGUAGE ,Subscriber_Key ,DSS_Start ,DSS_End ,CONSULT_INCLUDED ,SMS ,CREATED_DATE ,INDUSTRY ,PRODUCT1 ,PRODUCT2 ,PRODUCT3 ,PRODUCT4 ,PRODUCT5 ,PRODUCT6 ,PRODUCT7 ,PRODUCT8 ,PRODUCT9 ,PRODUCT10 FROM EHC_BOB
```

Comment: The answer provided by CodeRage is correct. I'd just like to add that OP wanted to use UNION ALL, while CodeRage's answer is using UNION. UNION ALL would take all values, UNION would remove any duplicates. In OPs case all records are unique so that wouldn't matter.

Note there are also tools like [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-14) that provide an easy UI for making SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you all!  This helps me significantly!